# ?Error in "switch : EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Tags: r

I am trying to assign the image channels back to `RGB` from `123`.
It shall be easy with `switch()`, but oddly, with totally identical cases, I assume, comes the different result: the `DT2` gives right answer, and the `DT1` gives error msg: `Error in switch(cc, "A", "B", "C") : EXPR must be a length 1 vector`

please find the toy examples, and thanks for the advice.

```
library(imager)
library(data.table)

DT1 <- setDT(as.data.frame(boats))[][, {
  RGB = switch(cc, "A", "B", "C")
  list(RGB=RGB)
}, by=value]

DT2 <- data.table(cc=1:3, value=1:6)[,{
     RGB = switch(cc, "A", "B", "C")
     list(RGB=RGB)
   }, by=value]
```

Comment: `switch` is not vectorized in R. Maybe you could prefer something like dplyr's `case_when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXPR` has to be of length one. Try this:

```
setDT(as.data.frame(boats))[][, {
  RGB = sapply(cc, \(cc) switch(cc, "A", "B", "C"))
  list(RGB=RGB)
}, by=value]
```

or

```
setDT(as.data.frame(boats))[][, {
  RGB = c("A", "B", "C")[cc]
  list(RGB=RGB)
}, by=value]
```

Comment: `RGB = c("A", "B", "C")[cc]` is a great move! thanks!